# "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect." Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

**My Error:**

```
{
    "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
}
```

**My Model:**

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    booking_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    booking_owner = models.TextField(max_length=20)
    booking_city = models.TextField(max_length=20)
    booking_place = models.TextField(max_length=20)
    booking_arrival = models.DateField()
    booking_departure = models.DateField()
    booking_vehicle = models.TextField(max_length=20)
    booking_amount = models.TextField(max_length=20)
    booking_payment_date = models.DateField(default=now)
    booking_status = models.TextField(max_length=10, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    booking_payment_status = models.TextField(max_length=10, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    booking_entrance_time = models.TimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    booking_exit_time = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.booking_id, self.booking_city)
```

**My Serializer:**

```
class AddBookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = '__all__'
```

**My View:**

```
class BookingAddAPI(APIView):

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        data = {}
        try:
            serializer = WitPark.serializers.AddBookingSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                data['status'] = status.HTTP_201_CREATED
                data['message'] = "Data saved successfully"
            else:
                data['status'] = status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT
                data['message'] = "Invalid data"
        except Exception as e:
            data['status'] = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
            data['message'] = "Failed to save the data"
            data['error'] = e

        return Response(data=data)
```

I have also other POST methods. This post method is working fine in localhost but not working in live server *(pythonanywhere.com)* All other methods are also working fine on live server except this one

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the  `X-CSRFToken` as a request header when making this POST API call.

More details can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/

Comment: But I am not doing this in other post request API's and these API's are working fine